# React functional component doesn't update the state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
function Example() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0)
  
  const someFunction= ()=>{
    ///some task that return a value
    let value = getFunction()
    setState(value)
    console.log(state) //prints 0 ???
  }

  return ( <></> );
}

export default Example;
```

As you can see the state doesn't change. What can I do to solve this. I tried using useEffect too

I tried using useEffect but no luck

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: I tried those. But no luck

Comment: But you're never triggering the `someFunction` function. How can it change? what exact behavior do you expect on this component?

Comment: I fixed he issue using useRef(). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is from [the React documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value):

> ##### I’ve updated the state, but logging gives me the old value
>
> ```
> function handleClick() {
>   console.log(count);  // 0
>
>   setCount(count + 1); // Request a re-render with 1
>   console.log(count);  // Still 0!
>
>   setTimeout(() => {
>     console.log(count); // Also 0!
>   }, 5000);
> }
> ```
>
> This is because states behaves like a snapshot. Updating state requests another render with the new state value, but does not affect the count JavaScript variable in your already-running event handler.

[This](https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates#react-batches-state-updates) is interesting too.